# How do I put a Platform::String^ into a Windows::Storage::Streams::Buffer?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

```
Platform::String^ m_json = L"{ \"Mode\": \"DeleteAllHumans\"}";
```

Later on I want to upload that string using the function:

`IAsyncOperation UploadBlobAsync(Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer jsonBlob, unsigned int bufferSize);`

I can't make use of Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer either.

Comment: Turning a string into a blob of bytes requires *encoding* it.  More than one way to do that, pretty important the whomever is on the other end of the buffer knows what you mean.  Utf8 is pretty boilerplate, WideCharToMultiByte() is readily available.

Comment: I believe I've found the answer:

`Windows::Storage::Streams::DataWriter configWriter;
configWriter.WriteString(m_json);

Windows::Storage::Streams::Buffer blobBuffer = configWriter.DetachBuffer();`